# Summer in Greece with SPARQL

Tags: geometry, sparql, rdf, geospatial, linked-data

I want to pose a query, which for every region of Greece, shall count the best bathing waters (i.e. the number of waters that show perfect quality). So the (ordered) result should be something like:

```
Crete  "2048"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer>        # Crete has 2048 perfect bathing waters
Santorini  "1024"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer> 
..
```

The problem for me is how to get the bathing waters related to a region. Then I should worry on how to collect different sums. I know how to order. Let's assume that `?concie_0` determines the quality; if > 40, then it is of perfect quality. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT ?municipality ?bw
WHERE { 
  ?regional_unit geo:έχει_επίσημο_όνομα "ΠΕΡΙΦΕΡΕΙΑΚΗ ΕΝΟΤΗΤΑ ΗΡΑΚΛΕΙΟΥ" .
  ?municipality geo:ανήκει_σε ?regional_unit .
  ?municipality geo:έχει_γεωμετρία ?geometry .

  ?bw geos:hasGeometry ?bw_geo .
  ?bw_geo geos:asWKT ?bw_geo_wkt .
  FILTER(strdf:within(?geometry, ?bw_geo_wkt)) .
  ?bw unt:has_concie_0 ?concie_0 .
  FILTER(?concie_0 > 40)
}
LIMIT 15
```

which gives:

```
municipality                                bw
http://geo.linkedopendata.gr/gag/id/9302    http://data.linkedeodata.eu/poiothta_ydatwn_kolymvhshs_2012/id/340
http://geo.linkedopendata.gr/gag/id/9302    http://data.linkedeodata.eu/poiothta_ydatwn_kolymvhshs_2012/id/456
http://geo.linkedopendata.gr/gag/id/9302    http://data.linkedeodata.eu/poiothta_ydatwn_kolymvhshs_2012/id/972
http://geo.linkedopendata.gr/gag/id/9302    http://data.linkedeodata.eu/poiothta_ydatwn_kolymvhshs_2012/id/1041
http://geo.linkedopendata.gr/gag/id/9302    http://data.linkedeodata.eu/poiothta_ydatwn_kolymvhshs_2012/id/1365
http://geo.linkedopendata.gr/gag/id/9302    http://data.linkedeodata.eu/poiothta_ydatwn_kolymvhshs_2012/id/1849
http://geo.linkedopendata.gr/gag/id/9306    http://data.linkedeodata.eu/poiothta_ydatwn_kolymvhshs_2012/id/340
http://geo.linkedopendata.gr/gag/id/9306    http://data.linkedeodata.eu/poiothta_ydatwn_kolymvhshs_2012/id/456 
...
```

I think that this *groups* the bathing waters with every regional unit. However, I do not know how to proceed, do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is change your `SELECT` clause to include a `COUNT`, add a `GROUP BY` clause that groups per municipality, and finally an `ORDER BY` clause that ensures the highest scores come first. Like this:

```
SELECT ?municipality (COUNT(?bw) as ?bwCount)
WHERE { 
  .... 
}
GROUP BY ?municipality
ORDER BY DESC(?bwCount)
```

Comment: Thanks Jeen, I have one last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530519/summer-in-greece-vol-2