# Summer in Greece, vol.2

Tags: group-by, sparql, rdf, geospatial, linked-data

Following this qeustion: [Summer in Greece with SPARQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36524518/summer-in-greece-with-sparql), since my memory runs out when executing this query, I would like to constrain the query between two regional units, but I can't group them:

```
SELECT * #?municipality (?bwCount1+?bwCount2 as ?bwCount)
WHERE { 
{
    SELECT (COUNT(?bw) as ?bwCount1) WHERE 
    {
           ?regional_unit geo:έχει_επίσημο_όνομα "ΠΕΡΙΦΕΡΕΙΑΚΗ ΕΝΟΤΗΤΑ ΗΡΑΚΛΕΙΟΥ" .
           ?municipality1 geo:ανήκει_σε ?regional_unit .
           ?municipality1 geo:έχει_γεωμετρία ?geometry .

           ?bw geos:hasGeometry ?bw_geo .
           ?bw_geo geos:asWKT ?bw_geo_wkt .
           FILTER(strdf:within(?geometry, ?bw_geo_wkt)) .
           ?bw unt:has_concie_0 ?concie_0 .
           FILTER(?concie_0 > 40)
    }
}
UNION
{
    SELECT (COUNT(?bw) as ?bwCount2) WHERE 
    {
           ?regional_unit geo:έχει_επίσημο_όνομα "ΠΕΡΙΦΕΡΕΙΑΚΗ ΕΝΟΤΗΤΑ ΛΕΣΒΟΥ" .
           ?municipality2 geo:ανήκει_σε ?regional_unit .
           ?municipality2 geo:έχει_γεωμετρία ?geometry .

           ?bw geos:hasGeometry ?bw_geo .
           ?bw_geo geos:asWKT ?bw_geo_wkt .
           FILTER(strdf:within(?geometry, ?bw_geo_wkt)) .
           ?bw unt:has_concie_0 ?concie_0 .
           FILTER(?concie_0 > 40)
    }
}
}
#GROUP BY ?municipality
#ORDER BY DESC(?bwCount)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: In terms of running out of memory, how large is your data store and how much memory do you have?

Comment: @scotthenninger big and small, it's expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may again be confusing yourself with the sub-selects, and this could be causing inefficient use of memory.  I see a couple of way of getting the results I believe you want (it is a bit unclear).  The first is by using `UNION`:

```
SELECT (COUNT(?bw1) as ?bwCount1) (COUNT(?bw2) as ?bwCount2)
WHERE { 
   ?municipality1 geo:ανήκει_σε ?regional_unit .
   ?municipality1 geo:έχει_γεωμετρία ?geometry .
   {
     ?regional_unit geo:έχει_επίσημο_όνομα "ΠΕΡΙΦΕΡΕΙΑΚΗ ΕΝΟΤΗΤΑ ΗΡΑΚΛΕΙΟΥ" .
     ?bw2 geos:hasGeometry ?bw_geo .
   }
   UNION
   {
     ?regional_unit geo:έχει_επίσημο_όνομα "ΠΕΡΙΦΕΡΕΙΑΚΗ ΕΝΟΤΗΤΑ ΛΕΣΒΟΥ" .
     ?bw1 geos:hasGeometry ?bw_geo .
   }
   ?bw_geo geos:asWKT ?bw_geo_wkt .
   FILTER(strdf:within(?geometry, ?bw_geo_wkt)) .
   ?bw unt:has_concie_0 ?concie_0 .
   FILTER(?concie_0 > 40)
}
```

A best practice here is to not repeat triple patterns inside the `UNION` unless they are part of the disjunction computation.

You could also do this with a `group by` on ?regional_unit:

```
SELECT (COUNT(?bw) as ?bwCount1)
WHERE { 
  VALUES ?name {"ΠΕΡΙΦΕΡΕΙΑΚΗ ΕΝΟΤΗΤΑ ΗΡΑΚΛΕΙΟΥ" "ΠΕΡΙΦΕΡΕΙΑΚΗ ΕΝΟΤΗΤΑ ΛΕΣΒΟΥ"}
  ?municipality1 geo:ανήκει_σε ?regional_unit .
  ?municipality1 geo:έχει_γεωμετρία ?geometry .
  ?regional_unit geo:έχει_επίσημο_όνομα ?name .
  ?bw geos:hasGeometry ?bw_geo .
  ?bw_geo geos:asWKT ?bw_geo_wkt .
  FILTER(strdf:within(?geometry, ?bw_geo_wkt)) .
  ?bw unt:has_concie_0 ?concie_0 .
  FILTER(?concie_0 > 40)
} GROUP BY ?regional_unit
```

Comment: Great, the first one works. Wish I could say the same thing for the 2nd; it gives me this error: `Lexical error at line 11, column 9. Encountered: " " (32), after : "VALUES"`

Comment: All looks good for the GROUP BY version.  What SPARQL engine are you using?

Comment: Scott, I am using Strabon and I am not sure how to answer your question. strabon.di.uoa.gr, but no worries, I will figure it out! ;)

Comment: Try parens around VALUES, e.g.: `VALUES (?name) ...`.  Otherwise, it could be a bug in Strabon's SPARQL interpreter.

Comment: That didn't work either Scott, so yes it might be a bug (I also tried some other ways)! In that case what would be a sample output?